# Rename df column name with dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following df and dict:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'x':[11,12,13,14]})
dict_ = {'new_a':['a','b','c'],'new_x':['x','y','z']}
```

I would like to check if column `'a'` and `'x'` exist in dict_ values, if so, rename them with their key values.

Desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'new_a':[1,2,3,4], 'new_x':[11,12,13,14]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert/flatten the dictionary and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
d2 = {k:v for v,l in dict_.items() for k in l}
# {'a': 'new_a', 'b': 'new_a', 'c': 'new_a',
#  'x': 'new_x', 'y': 'new_x', 'z': 'new_x'}

out = df.rename(columns=d2)
```

output:

```
   new_a  new_x
0      1     11
1      2     12
2      3     13
3      4     14
```

Comment: Yep, my solution was also going in this direction. Would this be a common way? I mean is it not too common to rename column names with dict keys?

Comment: It is quite common I think. I use it ;)